# Access VBA get current autofilter settings

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba, autofilter

Is there a way to find out what Autofilter has been applied to a query?

I can't use a form, as the database structure is changing (I can't do anything about it). So using a form and `Me.Filter` is sadly out. Is there anything similar for an opened select query?

What I'm doing now, but it makes me sick:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
```

I'd actually need to run another query against the filtered query. So: pasting everything into a new table would be OK, getting filter settings as a list of conditions or an SQL statement would be better.

Any ideas?

Comment: @HansUp When you are in Datasheet view, there is a filter on top of each field. Like in Excel. My users will want to use that, and I will have to detect what they have filtered for. Is this clear? I can add a screenshot.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Thanks. I never heard that feature called autofilter before.

Comment: @HansUp does it have a proper name? Filter is confusing in my opinion, it is used for like 10 things in Access...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the proper name --- autofilter may even be correct for all I know.  ;-)  Best I can suggest is to add the explanation in your comment to the question so no one else gets confused about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you know how to examine a form's user-applied filter, but you don't want to use a form because the database schema is still volatile, which means that your query's field set is likely to change.

In that case, create a simple container form with a subform control and use your query as the subform control's `SourceObject`.

Here is a simple example with a named query (*qryFoo2*) as `SourceObject` ...

```vb
? Forms!Form20!Child0.SourceObject
Query.qryFoo2
```

With no user filter applied ...

```vb
? Forms!Form20!Child0.Form.Filter

? Forms!Form20!Child0.Form.FilterOn
False
```

Then if I apply a (*"starts with 'h'"*) filter on my query's text field ...

```vb
? Forms!Form20!Child0.Form.Filter
([qryFoo2].[text_field] Like "h*")
? Forms!Form20!Child0.Form.FilterOn
True
```

Comment: Works like a charm, brilliant solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Neither have I heard of *Autofilter*, and I believe `Me.Filter` returns any applied filter (except in the recordsource, of course) of the form.

However, if you experience that this is not so, you should be able to use the *RecordsetClone* as it always returns the current records displayed in the form:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    While rs.EOF = False
        ' Loop rs and do stuff.
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I don't have a form. I have a query in datasheet view.